# How to compare strings containing &amp; in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to compare two strings, both containing value as `'New &amp; refinement'` in JavaScript without including any new library in my code.

Comment: String is New &amp; refinement

Comment: Isn't comparing values one of the first things you learn in a tutorial?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comparison_operators. What the string contains doesn't matter.

Comment: Please clarify your question more . . .

Answer (score 1):

This will test if you have '&' in your string:

```
var hasEntity = "New & refinement".match('&amp;').length > 0;
```

Comment: How does this answer the question now? *"How to compare strings containing &amp; in JavaScript"*

Comment: Look at the other comment, it's what OP needs. The question is not the best?

Answer (score 0):

```
"New & refinement" == "New & refinement"
"New &amp; refinement" == "New &amp; refinement"
```

Both are `true` in my browsers console.

If you mean that one string has an `&amp;` while the other one has a `&`, then replace the `&` with `&amp;` (or the other way round):

```
"New &amp; refinement" == "New & refinement".replace("&", "&amp;") //true
```

Comment: And if it's unknown which string or whether the string contains `&amp;` or `&`, replace all occurrences of `&amp;` with `&`. That's more reliable, otherwise you might end up with `&amp;amp;`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var s1="My string with &";
var s2="My string with &";
if(s1===s2){
  alert("equal");
}else{
  alert("not equal");
}
```